# jQuery AND selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I have a datagrid(asp.net) on my page. I would like to select all rows that has the word 'foo' in the first column AND the word 'bar' in the second column.

I only know how to do it for the first column.

```
jQuery('[id$="datagrid1"] tr td:contains(foo)')
```

Can anyone please let me know how to include the condition for the second column which has the word 'bar'?

**Edit:**
Also, how do I match the word exactly? As selector `contains` matches when the cell contains the word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selectors only get you so far. Use `.filter()` for greatest flexibility:

```
jQuery('[id$="datagrid1"] tr').filter(function () {
    return $('td:eq(0)', this).text() == 'foo' &&
        $('td:eq(1)', this).text() == 'bar';
});
```

- The `.filter()` functions iterates through each element and expects you to return `true` or `false` to indicate whether the element should be kept (matches).
- The `:eq()` selector lets you choose an index within the matched set.

Comment: I tried jerluc's suggestion and this code seems to work: `jQuery('[id$="datagrid1"] tr td:contains(foo)+td:contains(bar)')`

Comment: @StarCub, but as you mentioned, it won't match the word exactly. It also strictly doesn't look at only the 1st and 2nd columns - if you have more columns, it'll try to match the 2nd and 3rd, etc. as well.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
jQuery('[id$="datagrid1"] tr').filter(function(){
   var $tds = $(this).find("td");
   return ($tds.eq(0).text()=="foo" && $tds.eq(1).text()=="bar");
});
```

The same code more 'explained'

```
$trs = jQuery('[id$="datagrid1"] tr').filter(function(){
   var $first_td = $(this).find("td").eq(0);  //First column
   var $second_td = $(this).find("td").eq(1); //Second column
   return ($first_td.text()=="foo" && $second_td.text()=="bar"); //Condition to filter
});
```

This returns a set of `<tr>` that match the condition you want.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: thank you for your answer. I can only choose one answer and @Box9 answered first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [next-sibling selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/) assuming the second column `<td>` is adjacent to the first column `<td>`